# oracle 10g query against timestamp

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, date-arithmetic

I have troubles with queries from a table with a column `act_start timestamp(6)` in Oracle 10 DB. 
I would like to get all the rows older than 10 days  (rows with `act_start` field value older than 10 days from the current day) but I fail.

I tried with different queries  but they  don't work

For example:

```
select act_start 
  from wfmactionstates_tab 
 where act_start < (systimestamp -10).
```

All the table rows are returned;

```
select * 
  from wfmactionstates_tab 
 where cast(act_start as date) < (sysdate -10).
```

All the table rows are returned

Comment: you'd need to supply some test data + output really, as your SQL is correct. also show the output of `select systimestamp from dual`

Comment: You can also use `< systimestamp - interval '10' day`, but what you have should work.

Answer (score 2):

As others have observed, your queries are correct in SQL terms.  So if they return all rows only one conclusion is possible: *all your rows contain data which is more than ten days old* .

If this is not what you're expecting - and the fact that you're asking the question here suggests it isn't - then there must be a problem with your data.  The likelihood is it is a variant of the Y2K problem: somehow the data in your database is missing the century element of the date.  So what you think is 26-JAN-2013 is held in the database as 26-JAN-0013 (or perhaps - less likely - 26-JAN-1913).  Clearly that is more than ten days ago.

You can check whether this is the case easily enough:

```
select distinct to_char(your_date, 'CC') from your_table;
```

If I'm right this won't return `21` .  Then the question becomes, why do all the dates in your database have the wrong century?  Which is a question for the developers who wrote the data input sub-systems.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right. Date fields are stored in the wrong format 0013 instead of 2013